# JavaScript prompt() command

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I just learned about the prompt() command; I know that the prompt() command returns user input in the form of a string. I was messing with the program below, and I typed in **Per "Dead" Ohlin** for the male name. Why did this work and not cause any problems? "Per "Dead" Ohlin..." should have caused a problem. Does the interpreter automatically fix this by putting an escape character before the quotation marks?

```js
let nameOfTheKiller = prompt("Type in a male name.");
let nameOfTheVictim = prompt("Type in a female name.");
let nameOfDrug = prompt("Type in the name of a drug.");
let nameOfAlchoholicBeverage = prompt("Type in the name of an alchoholic beverage.");
let story = nameOfTheKiller   
story += " went to a diner, met " 
story += nameOfTheVictim + ", and asked her to hangout."  
story += " She said yes, so " + nameOfTheKiller + " took her home. As soon as they arrived to " 
story += nameOfTheKiller + " relax-location, " + nameOfTheKiller 
story += " pulled out " + nameOfDrug + " and " + nameOfAlchoholicBeverage + ". " 
story += nameOfTheKiller + " and " + nameOfTheVictim 
story += " started using the party favors and got really high and drunk. The party favors gave " 
story += nameOfTheKiller + " auditory halucinations that comanded him to kill " 
story += nameOfTheVictim + ", so he did." ;


alert("We are done asking you questions. We are generating a story for you. The story will be finished, shortly.");
document.write(story) ;
```

Comment: It doesn't need to add any escaping, no. Don't confuse quote marks which are part of a string variable, and quote marks which are hard-coded into your code to denote the beginning and end of a string literal. When you enter the data dynamically in the prompt, there are no such quote marks existing to denote the beginning and of the string, so there's no need to escape any quote marks which are typed in. You only need the escaping when hard-coding a string into the JS.

Comment: Escaping is only necessary in *source code* when a character is the same as a delimiting character (more generally when you want to remove the special meaning from a character). This is only relevant for the parser the processes the text. Here you are providing the value at runtime, dynamically. There is no issue here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`prompt` is not `eval` - whatever you pass to it will be interpreted as a *string*. Typing in

```
Per "Dead" Ohlin
```

when this line runs

```
let nameOfTheKiller = prompt("Type in a male name.");
```

is like doing

```
let nameOfTheKiller = `Per "Dead" Ohlin`;
```

Any characters you include in the string you enter which happen to also be valid string delimiters in Javascript will be interpreted as *those literal characters* (`"`, `'`, backtick), rather than as delimiters.