# Different output when using prompt()

Tags: javascript

Why does the output shows differently from a prompt compared to just assigning the variable?

Prompt:

```
var x = prompt(); // input "new \nline"
console.log(x); // output "new \nline"
```

Assigning the variable:

```
var x = 'new \nline';
console.log(x) 
//output
new line
```

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55173459/javascript-prompt-command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the Mozilla specification available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) the prompt message takes a "string" as an input, therefore, the escape character "\" is parsed as as string `\\n` and not as a new line `\n`, if you need to interpret it as a new line, you could try the following:

```js
var x = prompt(); // input "new \nline"
x = x.replace('\\n', '\n')
console.log(x);
```

Output:

```
new 
line
```